# NSSelectorFromString with named parameters in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

In Swift 2.3 I could dynamically call methods that had named parameters using `NSSelectorFromString("methodWithArg:")`. In Swift 3 I have to prepend `_` to a named parameter to allow it to be called without its name.

Is this still possible? See this playground code for a test case.

```
class Parent : NSObject {
    func parentSelector(_ arg: String) {
        print(" ---> Selected: \(arg)")
    }
    func test(_ selectorString: String, _ printString: String) {
        let selector : Selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorString)
        // if self.responds(to: selector) {
            self.perform(selector, with: printString)
        // }
    }
}

class Child : Parent {
    func childSelector(_ arg: String) {
        print(" ---> Child selected: \(arg)")
    }
    func namedChildSelector(arg: String) {
        print(" ---> Child selected: \(arg)")
    }
}

let parent = Parent()
parent.test("parentSelector:", "apple") // Works

let child = Child()
child.test("parentSelector:", "banana") // Works
child.test("childSelector:", "coffee") // Works
child.test("namedChildSelector:", "daffodil") // Throws `NSInvalidArgumentException`
child.test("namedChildSelector(_:)", "daffodil") // Throws `NSInvalidArgumentException`
```

Comment: `child.test("namedChildSelectorWithArg:", "daffodil")`

Comment: I tried both, both give an error. I'll edit to show that both do the same thing.

Comment: Are you sure?  The above line works for me in a Playground.

Comment: Ohh, I read that incorrectly. I added `WithArg:` and it worked. Swift 3 has some strange magic. Please post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Swift 3, the first parameter name is part of the selector name, so you need to add `WithArg` if the first argument name is `arg`:

```
child.test("namedChildSelectorWithArg:", "daffodil")
```

Comment: where is the documentation on this?

Comment: Note that the other gotcha here is if you have more than one parameter, the second doesn't have a capital first letter, e.g. `"namedSelectedWithArg:anotherArg:"`.